# Is there any netool to declare a maximum bandwidth (etc 2Gbits/sec) and make measurements between two nodes (client-server) without to exceed it?

Tags: tcp, bandwidth, iperf, onos

iam working with sdn controllers and more spesific with ONOS. When i run a topology iam trying with the help of iperf tool to take some measurements between two nodes at TCP mode, as far as bandwidth is concerned, and declare it to have a maximum value for example 2Gbits/sec.
The measurements between nodes have a duration of one minute every 5 seconds. I used the ''-b'' flag but it keeps the bandwidth constant, while I want 2Gbits/sec to be the maximum. For example the ideal would be to have different values like:

1.98
1.89
1.95
2.00
...
...
...

I am attaching the measurements I am trying to take to see if anyone can help me.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKJbl.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g640.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can try the  --near-congestion option or -b 1.8g,200m to set vbr. It's in the man page.

https://iperf2.sourceforge.io/iperf-manpage.html

Or use the flows code and step it that way. Flows requires passwordless ssh and python3's asyncio.